# Assigning initial value to variable

Tags: variables, optimization, gams-math

I do work on a mcp optimisation problem using Gams. 
I did set up all the equation but I cant assing an initial value. Obviously, the third equation is an attempt to model logistic growth at resource extraction but it is not working since I do not have an initial stock.

```
Equations

Objective_R(t) Objective Function
Movement_Stock(t) stock movement
Movement_ShadowPrice(t) shadow price
;

Objective_R(t)..
l(t)+c =g= (a - R(t))/b
;

Movement_Stock(t)..
l(t) + z*l(t) =g= l(t+1)
;

Movement_ShadowPrice(t)..
S(t-1)*g + S(t-1) -R(t) =e= S(t)
;

t0(t) = yes$(ord(t) eq 1);
S.L(t) = S0$t0(t)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How do I assing the initial value S0?

Comment: GAMS fails to capture S.L(t) = S0$0(t) which should represent the initial value of S(t) but it shows neither an error message nor does it take account of it. The stock simpy remains 0 at all times

Comment: What is the content of 0(t)? Can you post a runnable example to reproduce the issue? The snippet you posted does not indicate an error